# Sql query performance is varying though they are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables and their structure as below:

```
mysql> desc product;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| brand | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> desc sales;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| yearofsales | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here `id` is the foreign key.

And Queries are as follows:

1.

```
mysql> select brand,sum(price),yearofsales 
       from product p, sales s 
       where p.id=s.id 
       group by s.id,yearofsales;
+-------+------------+-------------+
| brand | sum(price) | yearofsales |
+-------+------------+-------------+
| Nike  |  917504000 | 2012        |
| FF    |  328990720 | 2010        |
| FF    |  328990720 | 2011        |
| FF    |  723517440 | 2012        |
+-------+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (1.91 sec)
```

2.

```
mysql> select brand,tmp.yearofsales,tmp.sum 
       from product p 
       join (
           select id,yearofsales,sum(price) as sum
           from sales
           group by yearofsales,id
       ) tmp on p.id=tmp.id ;
+-------+-------------+-----------+
| brand | yearofsales | sum       |
+-------+-------------+-----------+
| Nike  | 2012        | 917504000 |
| FF    | 2011        | 328990720 |
| FF    | 2012        | 723517440 |
| FF    | 2010        | 328990720 |
+-------+-------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (1.59 sec)
```

Question is: Why the second query takes less time than the first one? I have executed it multiple times in different order as well.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Considering that they start their statements with `mysql>`, I've assumed MySQL. :)

Comment: If you can take a look at the execution plan that will give you a clue as to where the time is being used up.  Being able to see the indexes and size of the table data will give clues as well.

Comment: Please, show the output of EXPLAIN for those queries.  Without knowing the query plans used, any answer will just be an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the execution plan for the two queries and the indexes on the two tables to see why one query takes more than the other. Also, you cannot run one simple test and trust the results, there are many factors that can impact the execution of queries, like the server being busy with something else when executing one query, so it runs slower. You'll have to run both queries a big number of times and then compare the averages.

However, it is highly recommended to use explicit joins instead of implicit joins:

```
SELECT brand, SUM(price), yearofsales
FROM product p
INNER JOIN sales s ON p.id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, yearofsales;
```